# Where do the neutral and ground wires go for a 30 amp generator inlet?

Tags: wiring

I am wiring a 30 amp generator inlet to my panel. I know the black and red will go into the breaker. I am not sure where to put the neutral and the ground. There are two buses in my panel that both have bare copper and white wires going into them. Some are even twisted together

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. Please [edit] your post to specify make/model of the generator and include a clear, focused picture of the info plate on it. Also, include pics of your panel including the label of the panel showing its make/model and all the descriptive text on it, too. Please confirm whether this is the main panel in the house or if it's a sub-panel. Once you've done that and while you're waiting for some answers, take the [tour] to learn a bit more about the community and how to get the best out of it.

Comment: With the grounding and grounded (ground and neutral) wires connected this indicated a main panel is it a main? the wires can go on the same buss as they are now however the bonding at the generator needs to be looked at the bonding strap in the generator will probably need to be lifted there are several different ways to wire separately derived systems and we need to know how your generator is wired to provide the safest advice. adding a mechanical interlock kit to the panel? When you say multiples connected together only grounds bare copper or green are allowed to be doubled or more if listed

Comment: Is this your main panel or a subpanel? What are you using for a transfer means?  Can you post photos of your panel please?